# Custom principal lost between AuthenticateRequest and AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an `asp.net mvc 4` web app in which I have a custom auth cookie containing encrypted user information. In my Global.asax.cs I decrypt the cookie, create a custom identity and principal, and set it on the context. This all works on my local machine which is running IIS 7.5 however when I publish to my staging setup with IIS 8 the custom principal doesn't stay on the context. Here's the gist of my code

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AuthenticateRequest(HttpContext.Current);
}

public virtual void AuthenticateRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var cookie = context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (cookie == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookie.Value))
    {
        return;
    }

    var rawJson = DecryptAuthCookie(cookie.value);
    var stub = AuthenticationStub.FromString(rawJson);

    var context = HttpContext.Current;

    var identity = new CustomIdentity(stub.Username, stub.FirstName, 
                          stub.LastName, stub.Email, stub.UserId, stub.UserType);

    var principal = new CustomPrincipal(identity);

    context.User = principal;
}
```

At this point I can attached a remote debugger and see that everything is set correctly. `context.User` is a `CustomPrincipal`

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {   
        // httpContext.User is a 
        // System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal not CustomPrincipal 
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

By the time I get here I can see that the `httpContext.User` is a `System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal` not `CustomPrincipal` this only happens on the IIS 8 machine, when I run it locally it is `CustomPrincipal` as expected.

Somewhere between `AuthenticateRequest` and my `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` my custom principal is wiped out and I don't know why.

Does anyone have any experience with this? All I have are wild guesses.

Comment: I'm curious. In the Global.asax, PostAuthorizeRequest and PostAuthenticateRequest are event handlers. Are we looking at two different things?

Comment: I'm having the same thing happen in my ApiController (webapi).  The CustomPrincipal is 'reverting' to a GenericPrincipal.  My Mvc(Controller) has the correct custom IIPrincipal...but not the ApiController.  G'aaaa.

Comment: I posted mine at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642169/webapi-custom-system-web-http-authorizeattribute-does-not-recognize-custom-claim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unbeknownst to you, you are fighting with other HttpModules. Try moving your code from AuthenticateRequest to PostAuthenticateRequest.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll play around with it. However when I move the code to `PostAuthenticateRequest` the auth cookie isn't in the request, but it is in `AuthenticateRequest`

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, try this: do everything *except* the assignment of context.User in AuthenticateRequest, and instead stuff the new principal into System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items.   (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["myPrincipal"] = principal;) Then, in PostAuthenticateRequest, set HttpContext.Current.User to System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["myPrincipal".

Comment: That did the trick! By any chance do you know what module is stomping on my request?

Comment: It depends upon the configuration of your Web app, but I've found that enabling SimpleMembership tends to muck with this, so that's a possibility. Have you enabled it for this app?